# golang lambda docker from alternative image

Tags: docker, go, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create a docker image for lambda running a golang handler, but which does not take from `public.ecr.aws/lambda/go:1` or `public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2`.

I tried to follow the steps on aws documentation for [alternative base image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/go-image.html#go-image-clients).

And also this tutorial:
https://hichaelmart.medium.com/using-container-images-with-aws-lambda-7ffbd23697f1

It just won't work. The lambda starts but won't serve any requests. Making a request:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{"body":{"name":"Test"}}'
```

Never returns.

If I use `public.ecr.aws/lambda/go:1` it works fine.

From what I've seen, it might be missing the "runtime interface" but their go api claims to be implementing it as a wrapper to the handler code.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.16

ADD https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator/releases/latest/download/aws-lambda-rie /usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie
RUN chmod 755 /usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie

WORKDIR /var/task

COPY main ./

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie", "/var/task/main"]
```

This is my lambda handler

```golang
type MyEvent struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func HandleRequest(_ context.Context, name MyEvent) (string, error) {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Hello %s!", name.Name), nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(HandleRequest)
}
```

The logs on the docker serving the requests are

```
15 May 2023 06:34:03,985 [INFO] (rapid) exec '/var/task/main' (cwd=/var/task, handler=/var/task/main)
15 May 2023 06:34:08,178 [INFO] (rapid) extensionsDisabledByLayer(/opt/disable-extensions-jwigqn8j) -> stat /opt/disable-extensions-jwigqn8j: no such file or directory
15 May 2023 06:34:08,180 [INFO] (rapid) Configuring and starting Operator Domain
15 May 2023 06:34:08,182 [INFO] (rapid) Starting runtime domain
15 May 2023 06:34:08,188 [WARNING] (rapid) Cannot list external agents error=open /opt/extensions: no such file or directory
START RequestId: dfbc9842-2a7b-4a3e-bfd2-2434aa126f63 Version: $LATEST
15 May 2023 06:34:08,198 [INFO] (rapid) Starting runtime without AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SESSION_TOKEN , Expected?: false
START RequestId: 5e0f07ac-46a3-42e0-8a60-851293544020 Version: $LATEST
```

Any help on what I need to add to the Dockerfile would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear how the `main` binary is built, but it's most likely that it's not built for `alpine`. If you check the log of the container, you should see something like this:

```
[WARNING] (rapid) First fatal error stored in appctx: Runtime.InvalidEntrypoint
[ERROR] (rapid) Init failed error=fork/exec /var/task/main: no such file or directory InvokeID=
```

The solutions are:

- either replace the base docker image to match what `main` is built for;
- or rebuild the `main` binary for `alpine`.

The `Dockerfile` below shows how to build the `main` binary for `alpine`:

```
# ==== build stage ====
FROM golang:1.18.4-alpine3.16 as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN go build -o main .

# ==== final stage ====
FROM alpine:3.16.1

ADD https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator/releases/latest/download/aws-lambda-rie /usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie
RUN chmod 755 /usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie

WORKDIR /var/task

COPY --from=build /app/main ./

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie", "/var/task/main"]
```

---

I'm also curious about why `aws-lambda-rie` works on `alpine`. And I found that it's built with `CGO_ENABLED=0` (see [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator/blob/c1cf0c518004962baa79bd82d5c4c2776e15073f/Makefile#L26-L27)). We can do the same thing because the simple demo don't need cgo:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o main .
```

This `main` binary works on `alpine` too.

Comment: Well, it's not exactly that, but it seems to be related to the build process somehow. This was part of a bigger project and used its go.mod. To do this step I had to create a new go.mod and it suddenly started working.

Comment: Have you checked the log of that container that failed to response to the request?

Comment: Yes. That error didn't appear. There's no error. I'll update the question to reflect the logs.

Comment: I saw the updated question. The log does not contain anything that is actionable. Is it possible to provide a minimal reproducer?

Comment: Not trivially. I'll try to figure out what in the original go.mod makes it break.

Comment: Found the issue, different version of the `github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go` package

Comment: @RaniSharim It should select the one based on the [Minimal version selection (MVS)](https://go.dev/ref/mod#minimal-version-selection) algorithm. Have you found out why the  selected version does not work?

Comment: No, I did not have the time to commit to it. Just updated the version in the base go.mod.